# Getting TemplateDoesNoteExsist Error in Django

Tags: python, django

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /
index.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    
Django Version: 1.6.5
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
index.html
Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py in find_template, line 131

Template-loader postmortem

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
C:\Users\Peter Na\documents\github\tutorial2\static\templates\index.html (File does not exist)
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\index.html (File does not exist)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\index.html (File does not exist)

TemplateDoesNotExist at /
index.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:
Django Version: 1.6.5
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
index.html
Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py in find_template, line 131
Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.6

Template-loader postmortem

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
C:\Users\Peter Na\documents\github\tutorial2\static\templates\index.html (File does not exist)
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\index.html (File does not exist)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\index.html (File does not exist)
```

in the Root Folder I do have a static folder>Templates>index.html. It seems like it cannot pick up the HTML file???

Comment: My template_dir is : TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "templates"),)

Answer (score 0):

You need add your template dir in the settings file.

```
import os

PROJECT_PATH = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

...

MEDIA_ROOT = PROJECT_PATH + '/media/'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    PROJECT_PATH + '/templates/'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do my project like this. I am using Djnago 1.6

```
import os

#Base root is for outside of the project structure
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

#Package root is for inside the project
PACKAGE_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PACKAGE_ROOT, "static"),
]

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PACKAGE_ROOT, "site_media", "media")

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = [
    "django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader",
    "django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader",
]

TEMPLATE_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PACKAGE_ROOT, "templates"),
]
```

Comment: I a following the tutorial online, it was part 5. I created the directory and of static/templates/index.html. I also linked it with the TEMPLATE_DIRS and the path should be the same but it seems like it is not picking up the html

Comment: What you mean it`s not picking up.. you tried what i suggested ?

Comment: I just tried something else. I set my template dir to TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    "static/templates",
)

Now it works???

Comment: why you are not separating `templates` and `static` in diffident folder